# Assembly x86 code thought process mistake in stack push/pop in a recursive function

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, x86-16

In the following image, there is an assembly code. No matter how much I tried, I can't quite understand how it works. Here is my thought process:
I assume that I input 3.

1. mov bp, sp //makes the bp pointer equal to sp
2. mov ax, [bp+2]// ax becomes equal to 3. 3 is stored 2 addresses above ax bp and 1 address above the return.
3. cmp a, 1 //3 is not equal to 1
4. jz exit // code does not jump to exit cause 3 does not equal 1.
5. push ax // 3 is now at bp-1
6. dec ax // ax=2
7. push ax // ax=2 is pushed on bp-2

   so now we have the stack

   ```
   return address
   bp
   3
   2
   ```
8. call func // the func is called again
9. add sp, 2 // return address after function finishes and sp+2 to delete the variables

the code continues until the stack looks like this:

```
return address
bp
3
2
```

**return to add sp,2**

```
bp
2
1
```

**return to add sp,2**

```
bp
```

now ax=1 and it will jump to exit.
what will the ret now do? How does it go on?
and how can I tell if it it `_cdecl` or `_stdcall`

[image: Assembly code]

[image: Thought process on stack]

Comment: `push ax` decrements `sp` by 2 not 1. The `ret` will return to the caller. In case of a recursion that will be after the `call func` and will continue with the `add sp, 2`. For the top level, it will return to the original caller. The function is `_cdecl` because the caller removes the arguments and the code does not use a `ret immediate`.

Comment: You can tell it's not `__stdcall` because it's not using `ret 2`.  The arg-passing is `__cdecl` because they're on the stack and popped by the caller. But this function clobbers BP and BX so it doesn't fully follow `__cdecl` either; those registers are normally call-preserved.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions doesn't mention call-preserved vs. call-clobbered registers in the table, and in 16-bit stuff this was less well agreed on than in 32-bit.  Earlier that article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl mentions regs.

Comment: Can you guys explain to me please how the code works. Would really save me.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a translation of your assembly program line-by-line to an equivalent C program. It might be easier to reason about since the operations are more visible in C.

The return address being pushed/popped by `call`/`ret` is simplified as a pointer decrement/increment, so the offsets relative to SP are the same as the asm. You can emulate this correctly (actually pushing code addresses and jumping to them) if you want, with [a GNU C extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html).

```
#include <inttypes.h>

#define SIZE 0x200
intptr_t virtual_stack[SIZE];
intptr_t *sp = virtual_stack + SIZE - 1;

intptr_t func(void) {
  intptr_t *bp = sp;   // mov bp, sp
  intptr_t ax = bp[1]; // mov ax, [bp + 2]
  if (ax == 1)     // cmp ax, 1
    goto exit;     // jz exit
  *--sp = ax;      // push ax
  --ax;            // dec ax
  *--sp = ax;      // push ax
  --sp; ax = func();   // call func  pushes a return address. 
  ++sp;            // add sp, 2
  intptr_t bx = *sp++; // pop bx
  ax = ax * bx;    // mul bx
exit:
  ++sp; return ax;  // ret  pops a return address; we just do a dummy operation
}
```

If you still have no clue, you can just call the function and see the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
    *sp-- = i;
    printf("%"PRIdPTR"\n", func());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output is,

```
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
```

which should be a very familiar sequence of numbers. In case it isn't, search the sequence in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C6%2C24%2C120%2C720%2C5040%2C40320&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: `*--sp = (intptr_t)func` isn't how `call` works; you push a return address (e.g. a C goto label in this function.)  But that happens as part of `ax = func()` if you're writing it as a C function call, not `goto`.  If you want to expand `call`, you could the GNU C extension that lets you take the address of a goto label within a function, allowing indirect goto (like `ret`) later.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html)

Comment: ["Godbolt" Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) may be of terrific interest for exploring here too!

Comment: @PeterCordes You're right. It's kind of fixed now.

Comment: I didn't mean to revert your edit, just stepped on it with a different edit I was making.  Incorporated that change now.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. I still don't understand what happens on the stack. I added a picture in my question of what I think is happening but don't know how it continues. I would really appreciate it if you can tell me. You seem to be an expert.

Comment: @nourghazal `bp` is not pushed to the stack. Otherwise, your picture is correct. Now, keep track of the value of `ax`, which is the return value.